# hardhat getNamedAccounts() does not work properly

Tags: javascript, solidity, hardhat

I'm following the course of 32 hours Learn *Blockchain, Solidity, ..* in Javascript and I'm stucked with an error [that others have](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72462523/typeerror-cannot-read-property-length-of-undefined-while-deploying-using-ha) but they solve because typos ecc.
I'm pretty sure at this point that the problem is not there but so what is the problem? I have my configuration file:

```
namedAccounts: {
    deployer: {
        default: 0, 
        1:0, // I even with this but nothing change
    },
  },
```

And I'm running everything in the hardhat default network, and when from the `00-deploy-mock.js` the script calls the function `getNamedAccounts()`:

```
module.exports = async function ({getNamedAccounts,deployments}){
    const {deploy,log} = deployments
    const {deployer} = await getNamedAccounts()
    
    log(deployer)
    if(developmentChains.includes(network.name)){
        log("Local network " + network.name +" deploying mocks....")
        await deploy("VRFCoordinatorV2Mock",{
            from: deployer,
            log: true,
            args: [BASE_FEE,GAS_PRICE_LINK] 
        })
        log("Mocks deployed !")
        log("--------------------------------------------------")
    }


}
```

`log(deployer)` prints `undefined`. and It returns the error:

`TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'length')`

The same process but using ganache instead run fine.
I have the hardhat-deploy plugin installed and i'm using the command `hardhat deploy`.

Any ideas ?

Comment: You should show `getNamedAccounts()`

Comment: it's manage by hardhat

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
const { ethers } = require("hardhat");

async function main() {
  const AMOUNT = ethers.utils.parseEther("0.1"); //bignumber
  const [deployer] = await ethers.getSigners();
  const iWTH = await ethers.getContractAt(
    "IWeth",
    "0xC02aaA39b223FE8D0A0e5C4F27eAD9083C756Cc2",
    deployer
  );

  const tx = await iWTH.deposit({ value: AMOUNT });
  await tx.wait(1);
  const wethBalance = await iWTH.balanceOf(deployer.address);
  console.log(`WETH OF ${deployer.address}:=  WETH ${wethBalance / 10 ** 18} `);
}

main().catch((error) => {
  console.error(error);
  process.exitCode = 1;
});
```

Try this  this worked for me .instead of getNamedAccounts use

```
const [deployer] = await ethers.getSigners();
```

Answer (score 0):

It's clear that deployer is not loaded properly.
This usually happens when you have not set up your module.exports in the file where you wrote the "getNamedAccounts()" function

Comment: getNamedAccounts() is managed by hardhat that read the configuration that I export, If i use --network ganache this does not happend

Comment: you need to show us the code where you are loading this. The error is definitely there

Comment: This function is managed by hardhat, I didn't write the code for that function.
[getNamedAccounts() is an hardhat function](https://github.com/wighawag/hardhat-deploy#configuration)

Comment: Yes but hardhat doesn't just simply materialise in the code by magic, you have to declare somewhere that you are using hardhat. Since you're not sharing the entire relevant part of the code we can't really help in a meaningful way. You could also maybe set up a jsfiddle if it's too much to share here.

Comment: I currently don't find the code of the function but [here you have the documentation of it](https://github.com/wighawag/hardhat-deploy#hardhat-environment-extensions)

Answer (score 0):

in your hardhat-config.js file under the module.exports section please include the following feilds

```
namedAccounts: {     
    deployer: {      
     default: 0,     
     1: 0,
    } } ,
```

also please ensure that the following imports are there

```
require("@nomiclabs/hardhat-waffle")
require("hardhat-gas-reporter")
require("@nomiclabs/hardhat-etherscan")
require("dotenv").config()
require("solidity-coverage")
require("hardhat-deploy")
```

although gas-reports and all are not necessary since you are fallowing the 31-hours course ....sooner or later you will be needing it

I guess it should work now

Answer (score 0):

In Hardhat.config.js file

> change getNamedAccounts to namedAccounts

```
 namedAccounts: {
        deployer: {
          default: 0,
        },
        users: {
          default: 1,
        },
      },
```

Also,
in deploy.js Make getNamedAccounts a function by adding

> "()"

```
const { deployer } = await getNamedAccounts;
```

to

```
const { deployer } = await getNamedAccounts();
```